# How to make a barlike chart but only with html and css

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have a database with lots of records and I have to make a foreach loop in order to get all that data. The problem is that a chart for every data would overload the page. So I need to make a barlike chart using two divs and one div(the blue one) to take percentage of the main one (the grey div) accourding to the value from that data. I did all of that but I don't know how to make the inner div build change it's percentage width according to how close it is from the highest value in my database. This is how I fetch the numbers shown in the right.

```
<?php echo @$item->{"media_count"}; ?>
```

I will attach an image so you can see how I need to make it look like.
[barlike chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvjJ2.png)

```
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody style="width: 401px; border: 0;">
         <?php foreach ($data->data->data as $key => $item):
            if (@$item->{"name"}) {
          ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo @$item->{"name"}; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="outer">
                            <div class="inner" style="width: 20%;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo @$item->{"media_count"}; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
        <?php }
        endforeach ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible .... have you tried something?

Comment: As DaniP mentioned you should show your work, and point out where you are stuck.  We are not going to do all of the work for you.  Please make an honest attempt to solve your problem first (Showing your work), then if you are stuck we can help.

Comment: Ok, I have 49 records. If I am going to use javascript it would be too much, so I was thinking of using html and css.

Comment: I will post some code in a moment

Comment: The problema is that I want the width of the inner div to change compared to a limit of 700.000. The closer the value I echo (<?php echo @$item->{"media_count"}; ?>) is to that limit the more width percentage get the inner div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the sort of layout you are looking for?

```css
.outer, .inner {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.outer {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 200px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" style="width: 20%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" style="width: 40%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" style="width: 60%;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a full width div, set the height and width and color it gray. Then, inside that div, create another div with no margin, set the height and color it blue. Set the width of the blue div to the width that you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning for the bars inside a relatively positioned div to make the bars follow the outer div.

```css
.outerGraph {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.value {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  right: 10px;
}
.bar {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20px;
  left: 10px;
}
.bar1 {
  top: 10px;
}
.bar2 {
  top: 40px;
}
.bar3 {
  top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerGraph">
  <div class="bar bar1" style="width: 75px;" title="88204"></div>
  <div class="value bar1">88204</div>

  <div class="bar bar2" style="width: 100px;" title="92784"></div>
  <div class="value bar2">92784</div>

  <div class="bar bar3" style="width: 200px;" title="100000"></div>
  <div class="value bar3">100000</div>


</div>
```

Use the `title` attribute on the bars for the hover effect and apply the bar[] class for both bars and their numbers.

Honestly, I cannot think of a reason you shouldnt just use javascript; you should tell us why you want this and post some code of your own